# Use separate channels or streams for emit in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a multi client chat application where clients can share both `texts` and `images`.
But I'm facing some issue like when user sends and image and the image is quite large and send a text just after it, the users have to wait until the image is fully recieved.
Is there a way to separately emit and recieve the text and image data? Like text is recieved but the image is still being recieved.
Currently I'm using one emitter for both the text and image.

```js
socket.emit('message', data, type, uId, msgId);
```

And if I have to use another protocol like `UDP` or `WebRTC` then which one would be the best? As far I know `UDP` cannot be used in the browser scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I've figuared out is,
Split the large image data into many [eg. 100] parts. Then use socket.emit();

```js
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = selectedImage;
    image.onload = async function() {
        let resized = resizeImage(image, image.mimetype); //resize it before sending. 
        //store image in 100 parts
        let partSize = resized.length / 100;
        let partArray = [];
        socket.emit('fileUploadStart', 'image', resized.length, id);
        for (let i = 0; i < resized.length; i += partSize) {
            partArray.push(resized.substring(i, i + partSize));
            socket.emit('fileUploadStream', resized.substring(i, i + partSize), id);
            await sleep(100); //wait a bit for other events to be sent while image is being sent.
        }
        socket.emit('fileUploadEnd', id);
```

Then finally gather the image parts back together.
I've used Map() on the server side and it's pretty fast.
`Server:`

```js
const imageDataMap = new Map();

socket.on('fileUploadStart', (...) => {
    imageDataMap.set(id, {metaData});
});
socket.on('fileUploadStream', (...) => {
    imageDataMap.get(id).data += chunk;
});
socket.on('fileUploadEnd', (...) => {
    //emit the data to other clients
});
```